# GNU parallel - how to handle column separator without spaces or new line?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I know the following scenario.

```
doit() {
  echo Doing it for $1
  sleep 2
  echo Done with $1
}

export -f doit
parallel --colsep ',' -0 doit ::: 1, 2, 3
```

Output1-desired:

Doing it for 1 
Done with 1 
Doing it for 2 
Done with 2 
Doing it for 3 
Done with 3

But, in my case, I don't have space `' '` between the arguments.
Here's my code.

```
doit() {
  echo Doing it for $1
  sleep 2
  echo Done with $1
}

export -f doit
parallel --colsep ',' -0 doit ::: 1,2,3
```

And I am getting the following output.

Output2:

Doing it for 1 
Done with 1

How can I get the first desired output with the second code block?

Comment: Can you use `tr` to fix the arguments? e.g. `parallel -0 doit ::: $(echo "1,2,3" | tr , ' ')`

Answer (score 3):

Use `-d` not `--colsep`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

doit() {
  local c
  for c; do
    echo Doing it for $c
    sleep 2
    echo Done with $c
  done
}

export -f doit
parallel -d ',' doit ::: 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what's required :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

doit() {
  echo Doing it for $1
  sleep 2
  echo Done with $1
}

export -f doit
parallel doit ::: $(IFS=,; read -ra A <<< 1,2,3; echo "${A[@]}")
```

When you use --colsep, `parallel` separates a single argument and feeds to `doit`

Comment: This is not correct. It's not running parallely. When I tried this solution, it has increased time to 6 seconds for printing it.

Comment: This probably works, but it's a lot less readable than $(echo 1,2,3 | tr ',' ' ')

Comment: @dstromberg, agreed, was just trying to do it in bash.